# WinUI3: How to bind one control to the size of another control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winui-3

I hope to get the height of a list, multiply it by 0.4, and set it to the Maxlength of a button.
For a reason, I don't want to use `Grid`, `StackPanel`, or other layout panel.
Here is what I have

```xml
<Window x:Class="App1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" />
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Click me!" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Use a Binding with a Converter. Use the ActualHeight of the ListBox as source property of the Binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight?view=winrt-22621#:%7E:text=Although%20it%20has%20an%20ActualHeightProperty%20backing%20field%2C%20ActualHeight%20does%20not%20raise%20property%20change%20notifications%20and%20it%20should%20be%20thought%20of%20as%20a%20regular%20property%20and%20not%20a%20dependency%20property.):

> Although it has an ActualHeightProperty backing field, ActualHeight does not raise property change notifications and it should be thought of as a regular property and not a dependency property.

You might be able to find some tricks to achieve this but the easiest way is to just use the `SizeChanged` event.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.listBox.SizeChanged += listBox_SizeChanged;
}

private void listBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.button.Height = this.listBox.ActualHeight * 0.4;
}
```